# How to share images cache between WKWebView and the rest app

Tags: ios, caching, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

I'm working on a news aggregation project like Flipboard. And lots of the images are the same in UITableView feed list and corresponding content rendered by WKWebView. It would save significant web traffic if a share cache exists.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, at the moment this is not possible. You could think of a way to actually display the images in a `WKWebView`, but that might be, depending on your use case, quite impractical.